# How to correctly select a line clamp?

Tags: battery-cable

I'm relocating a battery in my son's Impreza (from the front to the back). I have to run the positive battery cable from the rear up to the front in order to power the electrics which need to be powered. To run the new cable, I want to use line clamps to provide support for the cable and so it will not rub on the frame and create a short circuit. For reference, here's what a line clamp looks like:

[image]

I want to ensure I'm doing it correctly, so my question is, **How do you properly size the line clamp to what you are trying to support?** In my case, the cable I'm running has a width of ~.41". I selected 1/2" clamps. What I'm worried about is whether the extra space left in the clamps will allow for wiggle room and cause abrasion to the cable. Should I have picked a smaller size which would stretch the clamp around the cable and hold it more firmly or would have that been a mistake? Is there a rule of thumb for selecting these regardless of the size of what is being supported?

Comment: You could use heatshrink tube, duct tape or some rubber from the inner tube of a bicycle tire to fill the gap...

Comment: @Hobbes - I'll keep it in mind, depending on how much space there actually is to soak up. It may just be it'll work peachie.

Comment: I'd add a fuse near the battery in case that 20 ft power line gets damaged at some point. It might save a fire.

Comment: @cory - Not my car ... can go up in smoke for all I care ... I guess I'll ensure the door handles work, though :o) Good idea, though, really. I also bought some grommets to put into place I can run the cable through the body with. I still have to mount the battery in the trunk ... not *exactly* sure how I want to accomplish that. Probably just find a battery box which will work for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to hold the cable in place and to avoid chaffing, then you need a clamp that will grasp the cable. They make the same clamps you've pictured in 3/8" which would be a little snug, but wouldn't allow movement. The larger cables have more insulation (typically), so the snug fit should not damage it.

These work great. I have used these in aircraft applications, as well as automotive.

An alternate would be a nylon clamp which would not react if chafed through the insulation.

[image]